# React Native : Why alert is getting displayed before clicking on the button?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Can someone tell me as to why my alert is popping up when the app is ran ?.

This is the source code of my component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

const Button = () => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={Alert.alert('A', 'B')} style={buttonStyle}>
    <Text style={textStyle}> Log </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {

  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#27b535',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10

  },

  buttonStyle: {
    //flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#27b535',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }

};

export default Button;
```

As can be seen from the source code above, I am popping up an alert upon the button press but what happens is that as soon as my app is ran, this alert box is shown and the alert box does not show when I actually click on the button.

Can someone explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: You accepted the bad (yet working) answer, but bad answer. The other answer is a right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been answered but to resolve some other error adding this answer:

You should use function to call `Alert` rather than directly using it Thanks to @ KhalilKhalaf for pointing it out. [ref link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)

You had missed `() =>`

```
showAlert = () =>
{
  Alert.alert('A', 'B');
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAlert} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
```

Also

```
style = {styles.buttonStyle} // missed styles
<Text style={styles.textStyle}> Log </Text>
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to use the arrow functions in onPress. Better define the function instead, and pass its name. See more here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Comment: Thanks, updated code. I had created demo for that same but it was already answered so I kept that code

Comment: Nope. See reference in my first comment. Use something like `let myFunc = () => { /*do something*/ }` and then `onPress={this.myFunc}`. Else, everytime your (the) component renders, it will define a new function (performance hit -> BAD)

Answer (score 2):

You will often need to pass a function as a property for later execution.

The `() => ...` defines the **Arrow Function**.

Change this

```
onPress={Alert.alert('A', 'B')}
```

to

```
onPress={() => Alert.alert('A', 'B')}
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to use the arrow functions in onPress. Better define the function instead, and pass its name. See more here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the function to `onPress`. You are now calling `alert`, not passing the function to be called in `onPress`

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Alert.alert('A', 'B')} style={buttonStyle}>`

Comment: It is a bad practice to use the arrow functions in onPress. Better define the function instead, and pass its name. See more here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Comment: True, if you are good at JavaScript, better to consider adding a member function in React component class and bind it into `this` context in constructor.